# Output of ZipArchive() in tree format

Tags: php, tree, text-processing

Using PHP, I have this list of files, that I get by:

```
new ZipArchive();
```

I mean that it is in a zip file.

The file list is:

- docs/
- docs/INSTALL.html
- docs/auth_api.html
- docs/corners_right.gif
- docs/corners_right.png
- docs/COPYING
- docs/corners_left.png
- docs/bg_header.gif
- docs/CHANGELOG.html
- docs/coding-guidelines.html
- docs/hook_system.html
- docs/FAQ.html
- docs/site_logo.gif
- docs/AUTHORS
- docs/README.html
- docs/corners_left.gif
- docs/stylesheet.css
- docs/New Folder/
- docs/New Folder/New Text Document.txt
- docs/New Folder/New Folder/

I need a way to cut the dir name from each file path and make it a sub category.

So the output should be like this:

```
 docs/
  INSTALL.html
  auth_api.html
  corners_right.gif
  corners_right.png
  COPYING
  New Folder/
    New Text Document.txt
    New Folder/
      New Folder/
```

I hope it's not impossible

Comment: Just for displaying or for further processing in the file system?

Comment: becuase i hope any one solve it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11548872/110488 has a generalized solution to a similar problem, and might give you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

use `split('/',path)` or `preg_split` (for php 6) the documentation (with examples) can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php