# convert a `find` like output to a `tree` like output

Tags: unix, tree, text-processing, utility

This question is a generalized version of the [Output of ZipArchive() in tree format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872794/output-of-ziparchive-in-tree-format) question.

---

Just before I am wasting time on writing this (*nix command line) utility, it will be a good idea to find out if someone already wrote it. I would like a utility that will get as its' standard input a list such as the one returned by `find(1)` and will output something similar to the one by `tree(1)`

E.g.:

Input:

```
/fruit/apple/green
/fruit/apple/red
/fruit/apple/yellow
/fruit/banana/green
/fruit/banana/yellow
/fruit/orange/green
/fruit/orange/orange
/i_want_my_mommy
/person/men/bob
/person/men/david
/person/women/eve
```

Output

```
/
|-- fruit/
|   |-- apple/
|   |   |-- green
|   |   |-- red
|   |   `-- yellow
|   |-- banana/
|   |   |-- green
|   |   `-- yellow
|   `-- orange/
|       |-- green
|       `-- orange
|-- i_want_my_mommy
`-- person/
    |-- men/
    |   |-- bob
    |   `-- david
    `-- women/
        `-- eve
```

Usage should be something like:

```
list2tree --delimiter="/" < Input > Output
```

---

Edit0: It seems that I was not clear about the purpose of this exercise. I like the output of tree, but I want it for arbitrary input. It might not be part of any file system name-space.

Edit1: Fixed `person` branch on the output. Thanks, @Alnitak.

Comment: The output won't be reliable unless you arrange for the input file to have trailing `/` on directories.  Without that, the filter won't be able to tell the difference between an empty directory and a file. p.s. you've messed up the `person` branch of the tree...

Comment: What's wrong with `tree` (eg `tree -F`)?

Comment: To clarify on @ring0's excellent comment: http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I whipped up a Perl script that splits the paths (on "/"), creates a hash tree, and then prints the tree with Data::TreeDumper. Kinda hacky, but it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::TreeDumper;

my %tree;
while (<>) {
    my $t = \%tree;
    foreach my $part (split m!/!, $_) {
        next if $part eq '';
        chomp $part;
        $t->{$part} ||= {};
        $t = $t->{$part};
    }
}
sub check_tree {
    my $t = shift;
    foreach my $hash (values %$t) {
        undef $hash unless keys %$hash;
        check_tree($hash);
    }    
}
check_tree(\%tree);
my $output = DumpTree(\%tree);
$output =~ s/ = undef.*//g;
$output =~ s/ \[H\d+\].*//g;
print $output;
```

Here's the output:

```
$ perl test.pl test.data

|- fruit 
|  |- apple 
|  |  |- green
|  |  |- red
|  |  `- yellow
|  |- banana 
|  |  |- green
|  |  `- yellow
|  `- orange 
|     |- green
|     `- orange
|- i_want_my_mommy
`- person 
   |- men 
   |  |- bob
   |  `- david
   `- women 
      `- eve
```

Answer (score 14):

In my Debian 10 I have `tree v1.8.0`. It supports `--fromfile`.

> `--fromfile`
>   Reads a directory listing from a file rather than the file-system. Paths provided on the command line are files to read from rather than directories to search. The dot (`.`) directory indicates that `tree` should read paths from standard input.

This way I can feed `tree` with output from `find`:

```
find /foo | tree -d --fromfile .
```

Problems:

- If `tree` reads `/foo/whatever` or `foo/whatever` then `foo` will be reported as a *subdirectory* of `.`. Similarly with `./whatever`: `.` will be reported as an *additional* level named `.` under the top level `.`. So the results may not entirely meet your formal expectations, there will always be a top level `.` entry. It will be there even if `find` finds nothing or throws an error.
- Filenames with newlines will confuse `tree`. Using `find -print0` is not an option because there is no corresponding switch for `tree`.

Answer (score 2):

An other tool is [treeify](https://github.com/dzamlo/treeify) written in [Rust](https://rust-lang.org).

Assuming you have Rust installed get it with:

```
$ cargo install treeify
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally wrote what I hope will become the *python tree utils*. Find it at http://pytree.org

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `tree` myself but here's a simple thing that I wrote a few days ago that prints a tree of a directory. It doesn't expect input from find (which makes is different from your requirements) and doesn't do the `|-` display (which can be done with some small modifications). You have to call it like so `tree <base_path> <initial_indent>`. `intial_indent` is the number of characters the first "column" is indented.

```
function tree() {
    local root=$1
    local indent=$2
    cd $root
    for i in *
    do
    for j in $(seq 0 $indent)
    do 
        echo -n " "
    done
    if [ -d $i ]
    then
        echo "$i/"
        (tree $i $(expr $indent + 5))
    else
        echo $i
    fi
    done
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. Please see the "Edit:" in the question. I am not looking for the tree utility itself. `find` and `tree` are only there to illustrate the form of input and output, not its' content.